# What is the difference between "on" and " upon" in these sentences?

Tags: grammar

There are clauses like:

> This is an equipment that stiffens on the collisions.

and

> This is an equipment that stiffens upon the collisions.

What is the difference between **on** and **upon** in the above sentences?

Which one is more suitable for this situation?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the equipment and the collisions to which you are referring?  The second sentence sounds closer to being correct, as it is common to say "Upon impact, the drivers in each car were killed instantly."  Or, "Upon colliding, the cars careened off the highway."

Answer (score 1):

Neither one is acceptable, because the larger syntax is off. The proper way of saying this would be, "This equipment stiffens in a collision."